# ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations, usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (1). API issue?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, valueerror

Getting a Value Error in a quick python/pandas/matplotlib script I'm writing. Im not directly using setTicks or tick labels. Would this be considered an API error or is this functionality deprecated now?

This function does appear to still be supported which is reflected in the pandas docs [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html)

I was trying to find a solution where I didn't have to outright use matplotlib due to constraints I'm facing.

Code Snippet:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

df['C'].plot(kind="box")

df['S'].plot(kind="box")

plt.show()
```

This is the error that I get back:
[image: Error showing when running code]

Comment: Your code is missing reproducible data.  You seem to be plotting two boxplots on top of each other. Wouldn't it be better to use two subplots?